# SwiftUI app + Atlas App Services/Realm - Handle Sync errors

Tags: swiftui, error-handling, realm

I am designing a SwiftUI App to enable reporting of daily revenues/activities of a particular centre. (Using Realm Flexible Sync)
Not all App users can report the data - Sync permissions set on "RevenueReport" collection for read/ write if user.customdata.isCentreAdmin = true.
I have a function to save the data from the App. I want the user to be intimated if he tries to submit report that he does not have write permissions using app.syncmanager.errorhandler.

```
   if accApp.syncManager.errorHandler == nil {
            alertMessage = "report submitted"
            showAlertToggle.toggle()
        } else {
            accApp.syncManager.errorHandler = { error, session in
    
                    alertMessage = "You are not authorised to submit reports /n Please Log In, again"
                    showAlertToggle.toggle()
                }
```

This always shows up "report submitted" even when write permission error is seen in the debug area.
[image]

My function to save the report

```
    func saveRevRep() {
        let revIPDouble = Double(revenueIPD) ?? 0.0
        let revOPDouble = Double(revenueOPD) ?? 0.0
        let revenueTot = revIPDouble + revOPDouble
        let collectAmtDouble = Double(collectAmt) ?? 0.0
        let reps = users.first
        revenueOfCentre = reps!.centreName
        let rep = RevenueReport()
        rep.revenueReportedBy = revenueReportedBy!
        rep.revenueReportedById = revenueReportedById!
        rep.centreName = revenueOfCentre
        rep.revenueDate = revenueDate
        rep.revenueIPD = revIPDouble
        rep.revenueOPD = revOPDouble
        rep.revenueTot = revenueTot
        rep.collectAmt = collectAmtDouble
        $revReps.append(rep)
        
        accApp.syncManager.errorHandler = { error, session in
                alertTitle = "Artemis Cardiac Care Alert!"
                alertMessage = "You are not authorised to submit reports \n Please Log In, again"
                showAlertToggle.toggle()
            accApp.currentUser?.logOut { _ in

            }
            }
   
                            alertTitle = "Artemis Cardiac Care Alert!"
                            alertMessage = "Report submitted"
                            showAlertToggle.toggle()
    }
```

The syncManager.errorhandler correctly displays the alert on wrong submission without permissions. But, I also want to display confirmation to authorised user that report has been submitted.
If I add the second alert "Report submitted". That is the one that shows up regardless of the error or not. The syncManager.errorhandler block does not execute.

Comment: A general thought: If a user doesn't have permission to submit a report, then from a UI perspective, you should prevent them from doing one in the first place, right? If I was a user and went through the time and effort to create a report, just to find out that I am not allowed to submit it, I wouldn't be very happy. As far as the code goes we have no idea what `using app.syncmanager.errorhandler` is or what it does - to me it looks like you're checking to see if the syncManager has an error **handler**, not if there's an error. Can you clarify the question itself and include relevant code?

Comment: @JayThank you for the comments. YesI agree that a user should be informed beforehand. I do have an alert that pops up on navigating to the reports screen reminding the user that they can not submit reports unless they have proper permissions

Comment: screenshot updated above

Comment: So... I think you answered your own question, right? If you simply prevent them submitting a report in the first place, it will eliminate all of that code. e.g. if they don't submit a report at all, then you won't need to check for errors. Other than that, the question is still very vague; I will repeat my above comment: your code checks to see if there's an *error handler* not an error. Just because there's a handler, doesn't mean theres an error. e.g. this code `accApp.syncManager.errorHandler = { error, session` ensures that it will NEVER be nil.

Comment: And if it is, it would indicate this code `accApp.syncManager.errorHandler = { error, session` is not executing. Also, per above, we still don't know what this is `accApp.syncManager.errorHandler` or what it's supposed to do.